# How to add blank rows in a DataGridView in C# desktop application

Tags: c#, datagridview, desktop-application

I'm trying to create some blank rows in datagridview. Unfortunately I'm unable to do this.

How can I implement blank rows in the grid?

I just implemented like this..

```
dgvGetData.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
dgvGetData.Rows.Add(5);
```

But things are not working....

Comment: Is your DataGridView bound to data? If so you might need to set the data source's AllowNew Property to true.

Comment: The code you've written is fine. The problem is with the modifications you've made to `DataGridView`.

Comment: _unable to do that_ isn't a good enough explanation. Is there an error thrown?

Answer (score 3):

Have you added the columns prior to creating rows? An error is thrown if you have not.

One simple way to go about adding empty rows is this. First you need to add the Columns.

```
//You can assign the Column types while initializing
DataGridViewColumn d1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
DataGridViewColumn d2 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
DataGridViewColumn d3 = new DataGridViewImageColumn();

//Add Header Texts to be displayed on the Columns
d1.HeaderText = "Column 1"; 
d2.HeaderText = "Column 2";
d3.HeaderText = "Column 3";

//Add the Columns to the DataGridView
DataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(d1, d2, d3);

//Finally add the Rows
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(5);
```